# Gravitational force due to objects on Earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If all the objects on Earth attract each other ( due to gravitational force) then why don't they all move (or are pulled) towards each other?

Comment: With the greatest of care you can *measure* the mutual attraction of objects on Earth. [Cavendash was the first to do it successfully](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment). So the question you should be asking is *"Why don't I notice on a day-to-day basis?"*

Comment: There is a hypothesis that the changing gravitational influence of nearby objects -- specifically groundwater I think -- is a limit to the accuracy of very good pendulum clocks, so this is one way that it *can* be measured.  The hypothesis is not very well-tested because very accurate pendulum clocks are of limited interest now, push the ability of amateurs to make (big vacuum chambers are expensive), and there aren't many old ones in running order and suitably mounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They *do* pull in each other. Just far, far too little to make any difference. Especially compared with Earth's pull itself and compared with any kind of friction.

You can do the calculations yourself:

$$F=G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$$

Try to plug in the mass of a car of maybe 2000 kg and a person of maybe 100 kg, say 1 meter apart. The constant is $G=6.7\times 10^{-11}\;\mathrm{\frac{m^3}{kg\; s^2}}$:

$$F=G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}=6.7\times 10^{-11}\mathrm{\frac{m^3}{kg\; s^2}}\;\cdot\frac{2000\;\mathrm{kg}\cdot100\;\mathrm{kg}}{(1\;\mathrm m)^2}=0.000013\;\mathrm N$$

And compare the result with their *weights* (the gravitational pull from Earth),
$$F_{person}=mg=100\;\mathrm{kg}\cdot 9.8\;\mathrm{\frac{m}{s^2}}=980\;\mathrm N\\
F_{car}=mg=2000\;\mathrm{kg}\cdot 9.8\;\mathrm{\frac{m}{s^2}}=19600\;\mathrm N$$

But if you set up for equipment right, you *can* indeed detect the gravitational force from small objects. You'll need to eliminate any other force's influence. This is how gravitational force and the gravitational constant $G$ [was mesaured in the first place in the 1700s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment).